# php mysql search options combination

Tags: php, mysql, switch-statement, combinations

i have got 4 checkboxes for filterung mysql result. Checkboxes can be activated all or single, too. I don't know how to make sql statement. DO i really have to use all combined possibilities manually or is there a simplier solution? Perhaps with "switch"?

No as first statement i have:

```
if ($vart1 == "1" AND !isset($vart2) AND !isset($vart2) AND !isset($vart2) AND !isset($vart4)) {       
  $tname_sql .= " a.tdesc = 'option1' AND";             
};
```

How many variations are there?

Thank you for help.

Regards,
Olaf.

Comment: read about AND OR operators in mysql

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't really helps. I need the possibility of combination of all cases... better in php i think.

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what it is you want to achieve but I would guess that a simple a.tdesc IN('option1, 'option2') etc. would work for you. Use an array for the checkboxes if they are related to make it easier to manage in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a simple PHP function which returns `WHERE` or `AND` depending how many times has been called:

```
$wa = 0;
function whereAnd() {
    global $wa;
    if ($wa == 0) {
        $wa = 1;
        return ' WHERE ';
    } else {
        return ' AND ';
    }
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 t ";
if (isset($var1)) {
    $query .= whereAnd() . "t.field1 = " . $var1;
}
if (isset($var2)) {
    $query .= whereAnd() . "t.field2 = " . $var2;
}
if (isset($var3)) {
    $query .= whereAnd() . "t.field3 = " . $var3;
}
if (isset($var4)) {
    $query .= whereAnd() . "t.field4 = " . $var4;
}
```

First call will returns `WHERE`, all other calls will return `AND` no matter what kind of combinations you may have. You don't need to care about how many checkboxes are passed.